# How I can create one component for different JSON files with the same structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one thousand JSON files with the same structure. I need to create one the component that contains react-router to render those JSON Files

I wanted to create different components, but it not a solution for the React.js

JSON:

```
[{
link: "link",
prodLink: "https://link.com",
stageLink: "https://link.com",
status: "Failed",
titleDifferent: "No Diff",
bodyDiffernet: "No Diff"
},
{
link: "link",
prodLink: "https://link.com",
stageLink: "https://link.com",
status: "Failed",
titleDifferent: "No Diff",
bodyDiffernet: "No Diff"
}]
```

App.js

```
const Result1 = () => {
  return(
    <div>
    { 
      data1.map(({link, status,prodLink,stageLink, titleDifferent, bodyDiffernet})=> <Result 
        link = {link} 
        status = {status}
        prodLink = {prodLink}
        stageLink = {stageLink}
        titleDifferent = {titleDifferent}
        bodyDiffernet = {bodyDiffernet}
    />)}
    </div>
  )
}
class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <div>
              <a href ="/">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to={`/links/${data[0].name}`}>
                  <div>
                    <span>{data[0].name}</span>
                  </div>
              </Link>
              <Route exact path="/links/:name"  component = {Result1}/>
              </div>
           </Router> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default App;
```

Result.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Result.css';

class Result extends Component{
    render(){
        const {link, status,prodLink,stageLink, titleDifferent, bodyDiffernet} = this.props;

        return(
            <div className="container">
            <div>
              <span className='url'>{link}</span>
              <span> - </span>
              <span className='status'>{status}</span> 
              <span className='prod'><a href = {prodLink}>Prod</a></span>
              <span className='stage'><a href = {stageLink}>Stage</a></span>
            </div>
            <div className='diff-title'><span style= {{fontSize: 15}}>Title: </span>{titleDifferent}</div>
            <div>
                <span style= {{fontSize: 15}}>Body: </span>
                <span className='diff-body' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bodyDiffernet}}></span>
                </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Result;
```

Expected: that I create an app with 1000 links and when I click on of that link, that should be rendered Result.js component from one of the JSON files.
Actual: I have nothing.

Comment: Your data is *not* JSON, it's just JavaScript array and object literals.

Comment: What is data? data[0] has a name property but the data you show does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your magical data comes from and if it's available in your Result component but if it is then Result can look like this:

```
class Result extends Component {
  render() {
    const name = this.props.match.params.name;
    const item = data.find(item => item.name === name);
    if (!item) {
      return 'not found';
    }
    const {
      link,
      status,
      prodLink,
      stageLink,
      titleDifferent,
      bodyDiffernet,
    } = item;

    return 'your jsx';
  }
}
```

Then you can create your links like this:

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <div>
      <a href="/">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <Link
          to={`/links/${item.name}`}
          key={item.name}
        >
          <div>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ))}
      <Route
        exact
        path="/links/:name"
        component={Result}
      />
    </div>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: My data comes from different treads and written to the JSON files. That is a full example of the JSON:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cW4E_Da9BS4KMZEfQ7LlHeGNbceqeZdk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TomashGombosh That still does not explain where the `data` variable in your code comes from. Do you import it, are getting it through an xhr?

Comment: And that can be 1000 of those files. And I cannot upload to the React.js one JSON file with 400MB.

Comment: Sorry for my confuse @HMR
All App.js
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zGpz4RdoYuMjCJdBxdzg9EFusBQYsZZ6qfMnKHMqAMo/edit
Also, I can share with you a GitHub repo.

Comment: @TomashGombosh And the link you sent points to data that is an array of objects but none of the objects have a name property so what is the magical `data[0].name` in your code?

Comment: That is one more my try, that is JSON file with the path of the JSON files in the files directory. I try to create a JSON array with the name of the files and render component using data from the file path